# Cравнение элементов в std::list<std::list<...>>

Tags: c++, std-list

Имеется **std::list std::list<Point* > my_list**, где **Point** - структура с двумя полями: ***int x, y***

Необходимо проверить лист листов на совпадения элементов, т.е идентичность некоторых листов друг с другом и в итоге оставить уникальные листы. Изменять последовательность элементов в самих листах нельзя. Т.е,

***Вход***:

[   [(1,1),(2,1),(2,0)],
[(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)],  [(1,1),(2,1),(2,0)]   ]

***Выход***:

[ [(1,1),(2,1),(2,0)],   [(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)] ]

Варант **std::sort** с последующим **std::unique** не подходит, так как критерий сортировки не ясен.

Сооружать "Франкенштейна" с помощью циклов не хочется. Можно ли как-то сделать это с помощью встроенных функций стандартной библиотеки?

Comment: Можно ли обойтись только со встроенными -- не уверен. Вообще, попробуйте сделать множество (словарь, хэш-таблицу), где ключем записи будет пара -- x,y а телом -- счетчик. При первом проходе по спискам строите его. При втором, удаляете те элементы, у которых счетчик не равен 1

Comment: Как это "критерий сортировки неясен"? Сравнивайте сначала `x`, при равенстве `y`, проблем-то...

Comment: @Harry, да, действительно, сортировку можно сделать по убыванию или возрастанию значений в листах, но насколько это поможет использовать std::unique. Насколько я понимаю, в этом месте мы упремся в более серьёзную задачу: сможет ли эта функция распознать "уникальность" листов по совпадающим значениям?!

Comment: А пуркуа нет? Если есть четкое однозначное сравнение?

Comment: @Harry, пуркуа? Не встречал. Это какая функция?

Comment: "*Pourquoi Pas*" (фр.) — почему бы и нет? :)

Comment: @Harry, сложность ещё и в том, чтобы оставить в листах сохраненную последовательность структур Point, при этом листы имеют разное количество этих структур у себя, т.е размер листов разный. Получается, проще уже на этапе добавления элементов в лист проверять на идентичность листов с вновь добавляемым. Ладно, попробую обойти эту проблему

Comment: @Bizzarro, как-то невнимательно прочел вчера вопрос, осознал при чтении комментариев. Не увидел основного, надо сравнивать не точки в каждом подсписке, а подсписки целиком. Мне кажется это упрощает задачу. Вам надо вычислить уникальный идентификатор (например, md5 от всех точек подсписка) для каждого подсписка (это один проход). Заносите эти идентификаторы вместе с индексами (или указателями на начало подсписка) в вектор, сортируете его и оставляете уникальные. При втором проходе по "верхнему" списку удаляете те подсписки, которых не осталось в векторе.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Point{
    int x, y, sq;
    
public:
    Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y), sq(x*x + y*y) {}
    
    int get_x() const { return x; }
    int get_y() const { return y; }
    
    Point& operator=(const Point& other) {
        x = other.x;
        y = other.y;
        sq = other.sq;
        return *this;
    }
    
    bool operator<(const Point& other) const {
        return sq < other.sq;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const Point& other) const {
        return x == other.x && y == other.y;
    }
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Point&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Point& other) {
    out << "Point(";
    out << other.x << ", ";
    out << other.y << ")";
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::list<Point> lst = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}, {8, 9}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}};
    
    auto print = [&]() {
        for(Point& p: lst)
            std::cout << p << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    };
    
    print();
    
    lst.sort();
    print();
    
    lst.unique();
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: к "сожалению", тут нужно не элементы в листах отсортировать и оставить уникальные, а листы в листе- std::list<std::list<Point*>>, т.е оставить уникальные листы с сохранённой последовательность структур Point